# VBA Copying Formated Date Value only

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, date-formatting

I'm attempting to copy a formatted date value to another cell containing data, so I am unable to format the cell which is receiving the formatted date. Here is a snippet of the code im trying to work with

```
Sub test_sub()
Dim wsDash As Worksheet
Set wsDash = ActiveSheet
Dim dateStartCell As Range
Dim dateEndCell As Range
Dim allDates As Collection
Dim currentDateSter As Variant
Dim currentDate As Date
Dim II As Integer
Dim TargetDate As Variant

II = 60

Set dateStartCell = wsDash.Cells(7, 2)
Set dateEndCell = wsDash.Cells(7, 6)

Set allDates = GetDatesRange(dateStartCell.Value, dateEndCell.Value)

For Each currentDateSter In allDates
    currentDate = CDate(currentDateSter)
    wsDash.Cells(II, 1) = currentDate
    wsDash.Cells(II, 1).NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd"


    wsDash.Cells(II, 2) = "[""VNR""," & """" & wsDash.Cells(II, 1).Value & """" & ",""INTRO""]"
    II = II + 1

Next currentDateSter
End Sub
```

The problem is the format is not followed over when just looking at the cell. Is there a way to make the cell only the formatted value and remove the underlining date? I have tried creating a custom format with special characters each side to account for the extra data and then formatting in the date in "YYYYMMDD" but this doesn't seem to work.

can something be done earlier on to originally format the dates in desired format? I get my date range using a function GetDatesRange()

```
Function GetDatesRange(dateStart As Date, dateEnd As Date) As Collection
    Dim dates As New Collection
    Dim currentDate As Date
    currentDate = dateStart
    Do While currentDate <= dateEnd
        dates.Add currentDate
        currentDate = DateAdd("d", 1, currentDate)
    Loop
    Set GetDatesRange = dates
End Function
```

Also trying to copy values doesn't work as this just gives the date in integer value not in the number formatted style. so overall what needs to happen is the cell the dates are going into are in format yyyymmdd with data on either side of it.

Comment: `wsDash.Cells(II, 1).Text`, not `wsDash.Cells(II, 1).Value`.

Comment: Create a temporary variable `Dim strDate As String`; format its value in code `strDate = Format(CDate(currentDateSter), "yyyymmdd")`; write this value to the output field.

Comment: Both of these solutions work perfect for the problem at hand. Seems it was myself over complicating a simple task by using a wrong attribute type.